# Pivot Table : How to group by date if the column headers are month names?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, date

I have a table of expenses for multiple businesses and for each business, the expense is distributed into various accounts.  The expenses are reported on a monthly basis; thus the table is provided where the names of the months are the columns' header titles (see Table 1).   When using this table to create a Pivot Table, I can't group by date.

Table 1:
[image: Table 1]

I've tried to transpose the Table, but that created two Rows- Column Headers and, thus, can't use it to create a Pivot Table.  I have also tried to format the Columns's headers (Months' names) as in DATE Format but that didn't help.

My objective is to have a Pivot Table that looks like the one shown below.

Expected Pivot Table:
[image: Expected Pivot Table]

Any ideas how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is already pivoted and needs to be in a 1d list to pivot it in the way you want.  I used to do this on large Cross tab data tables using VBA but this can now be achieved using Power Query:

1. Select your table range.
2. Click `Data` on the ribbon.
3. Click `From Table/Range` under `Get and Transform Data` - your table
   will be loaded into the Power Query Editor.
4. Select your columns January through to December and right click the
   column header - click `Unpivot columns` You should now have two
   columns called 'Attribute' and 'Value' Right click 'Attribute' and
   rename it 'Month'.
5. You now have a better named table for pivoting.
6. In excel insert a new PivotTable and under `Create PivotTable` Check
   `Use an external data source` and click `Choose connection`

Select your Power Query table and you're good to go using the inserted Pivot Table.

Comment: JB, Thank you very much!   It worked beautifully.